# Impressão de valores de Lista Encadeada - Problema com ponteiros (Linguagem C)

Tags: c

Estou tendo problema para imprimir os valores da minha lista. Eu acredito que a função esteja certa, entretanto está acontecendo o seguinte erro quando tento compilar: "error: expect declaration specifiers or ´...´ before ´&´ token".

Acredito que haja um erro na parametrização da função. Eu estou usando o endereço da struct lista, mas não está funcionando.

Peço uma explicação do problema e da solução.

O problema acontece no

```
main() {
...
...

imprime_valores(&p2_main);

}
```

Código completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;

typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro *dado;
    struct nodo_st * prox;
} nodo;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;

nodo* CriarNodo(registro * p){
    nodo* n;
    n = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    n->dado = p;
    n->prox = NULL;
    return n;
}

void criarLista(lista *l){
    l->cauda = NULL;
    l->cabeca = NULL;
    l->tamanho = 0;
}

void insere_ini(lista *l, registro* dado){
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(novo == NULL){
        return 0; //falta de espaço
    };

    novo->dado = dado;
    novo->prox = l->cauda; //antigo primeiro aponta para o próximo
    l->cauda = novo; // novo nodo recebe ponteiro para começo
    printf("nodo implementado!!");
    return novo;
}

//FUNÇÕES PARA UTILIZAR NO MAIN

void imprime_nomes(lista *l){            // função que imprime os valores
    nodo *p = l->cauda;                             // Usando while, não é necessário estabelecer um loop para percorrer toda lista.
    while(p)
    {
        printf("Nome eh: %s\n", p->dado->nome);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}

void criar_registro(registro *p){                   //função para adicionar os contatos
    printf("Qual login para registro:\n");
    scanf("%s", &p->login);
    printf("Qual o nome do contato:\n");
    scanf("%s", &p->nome);
    printf("Qual valor para registrar:\n");
    scanf("%f", &p->valor);
}

int main(){
    registro *p1_main;
    lista   *p2_main;
    int escolha1, escolha2;

    criarLista(&p2_main); //cria a lista para salvar os nodos.

    do {
        printf("Digite 1 para continuar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &escolha1);

        criar_registro(&p1_main);
        insere_ini(&p2_main, &p1_main);
    }
    while ( escolha1 != 0);
}

imprime_nomes(&p2_main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O chamado de `imprime_nomes` está fora do `main`. O `main` deve parecer mais como:

```
int main(){
    registro *p1_main;
    lista   *p2_main;
    int escolha1, escolha2;

    criarLista(&p2_main); //cria a lista para salvar os nodos.

    do {
        printf("Digite 1 para continuar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &escolha1);

        criar_registro(&p1_main);
        insere_ini(&p2_main, &p1_main);
    }
    while ( escolha1 != 0);

    imprime_nomes(&p2_main);
}
```

Também tem mais dois erros.

1. `p2_main` é um ponteiro, mas você nunca deu um valor para `p2_main` antes de usar dentro de `criarLista`.
2. `criarLista` espera um `lista*`, ou seja, um ponteiro para uma `lista`, mas você passou `&p2_main`, o endereço de `p2_main`. Este endereço tem o tipo de `lista**`, ou um ponteiro para um ponteiro para uma `lista`.

Parece que os mesmos erros se aplicam a `p1_main`. Pode corregir os dois erros por trocar as linhas:

```
registro *p1_main;
lista *p2_main;
```

com:

```
registro p1_main;
lista p2_main;
```

Comment: Perfeito! Eu realizei as alterações e está funcionando parcialmente o programa. Quando ele imprime os valores que eu registrei, aparecem em sequência dos número de registros realizados, mas somente o último nome. Os nodos estão sendo ineridos corretamente na lista, mas ainda está faltando algo...